# EF Entity Framework update-database applies migration in code but database does not update

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have built some beginner classes for a code-first database in an ASP.NET web application (.NET Framework) project. I want this to be a code first project.

The server exists at `MY-PC\SQL2008R2`, database `MyDatabase`.

When I `Add-Migration` everything I want is there in terms of the tables/fields.

I have a connection string added in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" 
         connectionString="Server=My-PC\SQL2008R2;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=true;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In my migrations folder my `Configuration` class is:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

And in my `Data` folder, I have a `MyContext` class with:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TableA> TableAs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TableB> TableBs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TableC> TableCs { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<TableD> TableDs { get; set; } 
}
```

When I run `update-database -verbose` I get (I think this is where the error is but I'm oblivious to fix?):

> Target database is: 'MyContext' (DataSource: (localdb)\mssqllocaldb, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).

This is followed by applying migration/all the SQL code I would expect. I can run this on the DB directly and its fine.

What am I missing in terms of connecting to the database correctly. Do I need to set the connection somewhere else other than `web.config`? I find it odd it doesn't error given its not doing anything to the database, or is it but it's going somewhere I can't see?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just to be clear, when you execute `add-migration` or `update-database` commands make sure that you select your project that contains your DbContext as "Default project" in Package Manager Console and Set as Startup Project.
Second, after executing `add-migration` command Visual Studio will create migration class in "Migrations" folder. It will contain information what will happen with you database when you execute "update-database". If the migration file is blank, then you need to read console output from `add-migration` to understand what did go wrong.

If migration file looks good and you are ready to apply changes to your database, but `update-database` is failing and you can't figure out is it a problem with connection string or else. Again, read console output and if you have problem with connection string, then try to override your connection string in your `DbContext` class, example:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TableA> TableAs{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<TableB> TableBs{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<TableC> TableCs{ get; set; } 
    public DbSet<TableD> TableDs{ get; set; } 

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder dbContextOptionsBuilder)
    {
        dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=MY-PC\SQL2008R2;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    }
}
```

If this will help it means that you have a problem with dependency injection and you need to find why your connection string was not injected from your web.config

Answer (score -3):

```
connectionString="Server=My-PC\\SQL2008R2;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=MY-PC\\SQL2008R2;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
```

Can you update the connection string sentence like this?

Comment: dbContextOptionsBuilder could not be found - am I using the wrong version of EF/.Net?